# jQuery method chain - Method to get previous method's return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, return-value, chain

In this jQuery Method chain

```
$(SELECTOR1).find(SELECTOR2).doSomethingThatReturnsjQueryObject()
```

I would like to continue the chain with the return value of `$(SELECTOR1)`, so the outer DOM node itself.

I am looking for the best solution in **performance**.

- Shall I store the return value of `$(SELECTOR1)` in a variable for further use?
- Shall I use `.parents()` / `.closest()`?

Is there a *gentle method*, or an  *array-like-object trick* to get the last method's return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to tackle this kind of situations [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) was made.

```
$(SELECTOR1).find(SELECTOR2).end().doSomethingThatReturnsjQueryObject()
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/94gvS/)